# How to pass a 2D array of double between activities?

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity

I need to pass a 2D array of double between activities,this is what i wrote so far :
In the first activity (the sender ) :

```
Intent intent =new Intent(MapsActivity.this, RoutePath.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("other_locations", other_locations);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the second one (the receiver ):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
double[][] other_locations=(double[][]) b.getSerializable("other_locations");
```

But I got the ClassCastException, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to set ArrayExtra.. Search in google about the same

Comment: there is no set ArrayExtra for 2d arrays

Comment: convert 2D array one 1D array? you might also pass along the length of the first dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert **double 2D array to String 2D array** and send it just like you did :

To send :

```
b.putSerializable("array", other_locations_string);
```

To get :

```
String[][] value = (String[][]) b.getSerializable("array");
```

And then **again convert it into double 2d array**.

The reason for this behaviour is because Java (and consequently Android) does not let you cast Objects to primitive types, or arrays of primitive types. Why? Because Java considers a valid cast one which converts a super-class object to a sub-class object or vice versa. `String[][]` extends `Object`, while double and `double[][]` do not.

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is because Java (and consequently Android) does not let you cast Objects to primitive data types, or arrays of primitive data types, like double or int. This is because while String[][] extends Object, double[][] does not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Convert 2D Array into Hashmap and then use it

```
Map<Double, Double> map = new HashMap<Double, Double>(other_locations.length);
for (Double[] mapping : other_locations)
{
    map.put(mapping[0], mapping[1]);
}
```

And set map as intent extra and get the extra in second activity